# Configuring jacoco for integration and unit test reporting in Sonarqube with Powermock

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, instrumentation, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using Sonarqube to keep track of both unit and integration test coverage for a multi-module Maven project.

This was the existing profile in the parent pom.xml that was used to generate the Sonarqube report locally before I made the change:

**Profile that generates all unit test coverage locally in Sonarqube**

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>coverage</id>
    <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
       <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
       <sonar.projectName>plan-advantage-serverless-${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectName>
       <sonar.projectKey>${project.groupId}-MPA-${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectKey>
       <sonar.exclusions>file:**/generated-sources/**,**/*Model.java,**/models/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
       <sonar.test.exclusions>**/test/*</sonar.test.exclusions>
       <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
       <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
       <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <append>true</append>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/test/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-instrument</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
              <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
              <jacoco-agent.destfile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</jacoco-agent.destfile>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>

        <dependencies>
          <!-- needed for powermock to run correctly with surefire-->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0.1254</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

This is generating the expected test coverage (sans integration tests) in
Sonarqube locally when I run `mvn clean install -P coverage sonar:sonar`.

I've so far been able to get integration coverage added as a proof of concept using the following addition
to the parent pom.xml:

**pom.xml that includes integration test coverage in Sonarqube but excludes some unit tests**

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version> . <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
  <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
  <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
  <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
</properties>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>agent-for-ut</id>
              <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <append>true</append>
                  <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
              <id>agent-for-it</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <append>true</append>
                  <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This was inspired by the example found [here](https://github.com/acntech/jacoco-multimodule-maven).

However, when I run it with the command `mvn clean install failsafe:integration-test sonar:sonar`, it causes some of the unit tests which were previously being covered to not show up in the Sonarqube output. I believe that the prepare-agent and prepare-agent integrationgoals are using on-the-fly instrumentation. According to JaCoCo's docs, on-the-fly instrumentation is not possible while using PowerMock (which my project is utilizing), so we have to use the offline instrumentation for JaCoCo.

I looked at this [example](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2018/02/20/jacoco-reports-missing-code-coverage-for-tests-using-powermock/) for using offline instrumentation and used the following pom.xml with the command `mvn clean install test sonar:sonar`:

**parent pom.xml that fails to build due to NoClassDefFound errors**

```
<build>
...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-instrument</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions> 
  </plugin>
</build>
```

And here's the resulting error: [image]

Any ideas for the proper pom.xml configuration to enable offline instrumentation to get integration and unit test coverage to show up in Sonarqube?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 10 months old, but for anyone else coming across this, you need to add this to your dependencies in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```